# Maven doesn't build -runner.jar

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-native

I have generated a new project with the archetype and I have run the following maven

`./mvnw -Dskiptests clean package`

It should build two jar files xxx.jar and xx-runner.jar but it only build one (xxx.jar).

I have configured JAVA_HOME and GRAALVM_HOME pointing to the GraalVM that I have downloaded.

I have installed the Native Image.

My OS is UBUNTU

Maven should build the two JAR files but I don't why. Could someone help me.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------< es.olivar.jaen:atomic-fruit-service >-----------------
[INFO] Building atomic-fruit-service 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ atomic-fruit-service ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/sobremesa/Documents/Develop/java/quarkus/poc/atomic-fruit-service/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ atomic-fruit-service ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:2.11.3.Final:generate-code (default) @ atomic-fruit-service ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ atomic-fruit-service ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /home/sobremesa/Documents/Develop/java/quarkus/poc/atomic-fruit-service/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:2.11.3.Final:generate-code-tests (default) @ atomic-fruit-service ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ atomic-fruit-service ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/sobremesa/Documents/Develop/java/quarkus/poc/atomic-fruit-service/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ atomic-fruit-service ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to /home/sobremesa/Documents/Develop/java/quarkus/poc/atomic-fruit-service/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M7:test (default-test) @ atomic-fruit-service ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ atomic-fruit-service ---
[INFO] Building jar: /home/sobremesa/Documents/Develop/java/quarkus/poc/atomic-fruit-service/target/atomic-fruit-service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:2.11.3.Final:build (default) @ atomic-fruit-service ---
[INFO] [io.quarkus.deployment.QuarkusAugmentor] Quarkus augmentation completed in 1475ms
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  6.615 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-08-29T23:38:29+02:00
```

Thank very much indeed.

Comment: Can you add maven logs ?

Comment: updated. I'm following a tutorial and in this tutorial the xxx-runner.jar in built in:
`[INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:2.11.3.Final:build (default) @ atomic-fruit-service ---
[INFO] [io.quarkus.deployment.QuarkusAugmentor] Quarkus augmentation completed in 1475ms`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output jar is `target/quarkus-app/quarkus-run.jar`

Comment: If it works for you, it's best if you accept the answer so future readers know very quickly that it works